# Get the current system datetime

Tags: c#

I use my "epoch" as

```
Datetime myepoch=new DateTime(2005,11,11,7,0,0);
```

But I'd like it to be compatible with all the systems my exe intends to run on (machines in Asia and machines in Europe or America, for example, that is to change myepoche appropriately with the Datetime.Now). What culture class should I look into ?

Comment: Use DateTime.UtcNow and myUtcDateTime.ToLocalTime() to get local time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be best served using an invariant culture as your epoch - eg UTC:

```
Datetime myEpoch = new DateTime(2005, 11, 11, 7, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Using an invariant culture makes reasoning about times and dates far simpler.

If you are going to be doing a lot of work around dates and times, I'd recommend having a look at [the noda time blog](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/) for some of the lessons they've learned as well as possibly using some of the libraries that they've created.

Comment: +1 - I agree. Internal times should always be UTC/GMT and culture invariant, only referring to local machine culture when accepting date strings from user input or displaying date strings for user consumption. DateTime.Now can even cause problems on machines with the same culture, if for example whether daylight saving time is taken into account or not.

Answer (score 2):

Work with a DateTime object, with that you can get both local and universal time

```
var tmpTime =  DateTime.Now;
var localTime = tmpTime.ToLocalTime();
var universalTime = tmpTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: ups, to late same solution like @rich.okelly +1